# Why do the rasterio Resampling methods ‘max’, ‘min’, ‘med’, ‘q1’, ‘q3’ give a segmentation fault?

Tags: python, gdal, rasterio

I want to resample a georeferend raster .tif file with Python using rasterio. Here is the example I found [example](https://rasterio.readthedocs.io/en/latest/topics/resampling.html) and the documentaion of the [resampling methods](https://rasterio.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/rasterio.enums.html#rasterio.enums.Resampling).

When I am using the following methods ‘max’, ‘min’, ‘med’, ‘q1’, ‘q3’ which are only supported in GDAL >= 2.0.0 the program fails.

I am using a conda environment and rasterio.**gdal_version** gives me version 3.0.4.

When I run the following code (i.e. almost the example code):

```
raster = Path('dsm_EPSG_4839_cropped.tif')

import rasterio
from rasterio.enums import Resampling

upscale_factor = 1/(2**5)

with rasterio.open(raster) as dataset:

    # resample data to target shape
    data = dataset.read(
        out_shape=(
            dataset.count,
            int(dataset.height * upscale_factor),
            int(dataset.width * upscale_factor)
        ),
        resampling=Resampling.max
    )

    # scale image transform
    transform = dataset.transform * dataset.transform.scale(
        (dataset.width / data.shape[-1]),
        (dataset.height / data.shape[-2])
    )
```

I am getting the following error:

```
Segmentation fault: 11
```

How do I solve the issue and get the example to run without the segmentation fault?

Comment: I ran into this same issue, and have opened an issue on the rasterio github repo. https://github.com/mapbox/rasterio/issues/1930

Comment: thats great thanks for opening an issue. I also opened one here https://github.com/conda-forge/rasterio-feedstock/issues/163

Comment: Fixed https://github.com/rasterio/rasterio/issues/1930